# how to not overwrite file in python in different os path

Tags: python, file, filenames

so i want to avoid overwrite the file name that existed. but i don't know how to combine the code with mycode. please help me

here's my code for write file:

```
def filepass(f):
    print(f)
    with open ('media/pass/'+'filepass.txt', 'a') as fo:
        fo.write(f)
        fo.close()
    return fo
```

and here's the code to create number in name filepass:

```
def build_filename(name, num=0):
    root, ext = os.path.splitext(name)
    print(root)
    return '%s%d%s' % (root, num, ext) if num else name

def find_next_filename(name, max_tries=20):
    if not os.path.exists(name): return name
    else:
        for i in range(max_tries):
            test_name = build_filename(name, i+1)
            if not os.path.exists(test_name): return test_name
        return None
```

all i want is to create filename : filepass.txt, filepass1.txt, filepass2.txt

Comment: Uh, what is your question? How to call `find_next_filename`?

Comment: how to use the func build_filename and find_next_filename into func filepass? all i want just to create filename : filepass.txt, filepass1.txt, filepass2.txt @tripleee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
def filepass(f):
    print(f)
    filename = find_next_filename('media/pass/filepass.txt')
    with open (filename, 'a') as fo:
        fo.write(f)
        # you don't need to close when you use "with open";
    # but then it doesn't make sense to return a closed file handle
    # maybe let's return the filename instead
    return filename
```